# cursor jump up and down using step over debugging

Tags: c++, debugging

I encounter a very weird problem. I am using the step over to debug my code. I was expected that the cursor should move line by line sequentially. But the following phenomenon occurs

```
    using namespace std;
    ranlux48_base generator(1);
    uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform(0.0, 1.0); 

1   int main()
2   {
3        double R1 = uniform(generator);
4        cout << R1 << endl;
5        if (R1 < pH)
6        {
7           Quality[i] = vH;
8        }
9        else
10       {
11          Quality[i] = vL;
12       }
13       cout << Quality[i] << endl;
14   }
```

The weird thing is the following: the cursor first moves to line 3, try to generate a random number, then it moves to line 4 (looks like line 3 has already been executed), but then it moves back to line 3, and then moves to line 4, then it executes the line 4 and print out the random number. Why the cursor move back?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you compiled your code using your compiler's default optimization settings, which gives the compiler greater freedom in reordering compiled code around, for optimization purposes.

As you've discovered, this makes debugging a painful experience.

Turn off all optimization settings offered by your compiler. That'll make the generated code run a little bit slower, but makes it easier to debug it.

Comment: When I try to watch some variables, it also says "due to optimization, the variable is not available" something like that. So I think you are right. How to turn off this optimization setting? I am sorry, I am very new to C++

Comment: You have nothing to apologize for. This is a legitimate question.

Comment: Different compilers work differently. Check the documentation for your C++ compiler.